# What’s the SQL column type for Java double

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, double

In Hibernate, there are different column types for different Java objects. Typically, I have:

```
Java     MySQL column definition
-------  ----------------------------------------------------
String   varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
int      int(11) DEFAULT NULL
boolean  tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL
```

**What is the MySQL type to use for Java’s `double`?** If there are several possibilities, I prefer the better readable. I.e., for `enum` we use `varchar` and not `int`, though possible, because i.e. `PREVIEW` is better to understand as `3` when browsing the database.

I have read but not fully understood that the Hibernate double type implies definitions of ‘precision’ and ‘scale’ (aka. ‘m, d’). So, if it plays a role: The double I am planning to store is a scale factor, such as found on photocopiers. A scale of 1 is a 1:1 copy, where a scale of ≈1.414 (technically, `1 ÷ √(2)`) will double the paper size. Mathematically limits are that the scale must always be >0 and will unlikely be above 1,000%. But preferably, I would like to map Java’s `double` with the same precision that Java uses internally.

Comment: See the data types mappings here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html

Comment: equivalent type of java double for oracle https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljdoubleprecision.html

Comment: Does this mean no parentheses at all? `double DEFAULT NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Double datatype in sql then can use Number Datatype in sql. this will help to store float value as well as int value.